# Checking if image is ".attached?" when attaching same image to multiple models fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm trying to attach the same active storage image to two different models, reason being, I don't want two copies of the files stored, and I want to optimize DB queries so that I can just query "activity" to show the images, and not have to query both activity and posts.
The image attaches, but when i use the command.attach? it returns false for the activities. But it shows it has an image when I do @activity.image

Using Active Storage, here is my code

```
    @post.image.attach(io: File.open(image_file), filename: file_name)
    @activity.image.attach(@post.image)
```

In the console:

```
    >@post.image.attached?
=> **true**

    >@post.image
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000055d2dd844aa8 @name="image", @record=...

    >@activity.image
=> #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x000055d2dd8529f0 @name="image", @record=...    

    >@activity.image.attached?
=> **false**
```

In the views:

```
<%= image_tag @post.image %>  **IMAGE SHOWS UP**
<%= image_tag @activity.image %>  **NO IMAGE**
```

Comment: Try to attach an image to activity same way as post

Comment: Check my answer. Also let me know the exact scenario. Will `@post` have one image and the same might be referred in activity? Will `@activity` will have images from post and its own images?.

Answer (score 0):

The attach method expects a file object as params. Please refer [attach(attachable)](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html). If you want to use the same image/attachment for 2 models, then you can upload in one model and use the url reference in other model.

```
@post.image.url
```

this can be used and saved as string: attachment url in activity model. Thus same file can be referred from both. But if the activity model might include new attachments as well then it is better to have 2 copies. Also if the image is removed from referenced model, then the other model might get affected.

Comment: undefined method `url' for #<ActiveStorage::Attached::One:0x00007f76c4ec5580>